# Global array remains empty

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to update my global array, but it remains null after I submit a text value(.name) through a submit button.

Please tell me how I can keep track of text values in my global array. Thank you.

```
var display_name = [];
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () =>{
  document.querySelector("#form1").onsubmit = () => {
    let name = document.querySelector(".name").value;
    display_name.push(name);
};

});
```

Answer (score 1):

When the form is submitted, a new page is loaded. It loads the URL in the `action` property of the form. So, your variable goes away.

If you don't want that to happen, prevent the form from being submitted with [`preventDefault`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault).

For example ...

```js
const name_list = [];
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (e) => {
  const names = document.querySelector(`.names`);
  const add_button = document.querySelector(`.names--add_button`);
  
  names.addEventListener('submit', e => e.preventDefault());
  add_button.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    const name = document.querySelector(`.names--name`);
    const collected = document.querySelector(`.names--collected`);
    
    name_list.push(name.value);
    
    collected.innerHTML += `<li>${name.value}</li>`;
    
    name.value = ``;
    name.focus();
  });
});
```

```css
body { background: snow; }
```

```html
<form class="names" action="#" method="post">
  <label>Name: <input type="text" name="name" class="names--name"></label>
  <button class="names--add_button">Add To List</button>
  
  <div>Names Collected:</div>
  <ul class="names--collected">
  </ul>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am see at the moment it's working perfect. but you want add value every time when you click the button. so just changed the type of your 
`<button type="submit">` to `<button type="button">`

because when you click on submit page automatically reload in html, an the 2nd thing you need to change your event from  `onsubmit` to `onclick` and your button to it instead of your form.

```
var display_name = [];

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () =>{
  document.querySelector("#button1").onclick = () => {
    let name = document.querySelector(".name").value;
    display_name.push(name);
  };
});
```